# Scale the real part of complex numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a vector of complex numbers (the result of a FFT) and I would like to scale only the real part of the complex numbers by factors in another vector.

#### Example

```
cplxarr= np.array([1+2j, 3+1j, 7-2j])
factarr= np.array([.5, .6, .2])
# desired result of cplxarr * factarr :
# np.array([.5+2j 1.8+1j 1.4-2j])
```

(Yes, it's about human-hearing frequency response in a very specific setting.)
Obviously the multiplication with the vectors as above scales the imaginary parts too.

How do I set up `factarr` and what operation do I have to do in order to achieve the desired result? If it's possible at all, that is, without separating the real and imaginary parts, scaling the real parts and reassembling as a new complex vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
>>> factarr*cplxarr.real + (1j)*cplxarr.imag
array([ 0.5+2.j,  1.8+1.j,  1.4-2.j])
```

Not sure if it's the best way though.

---

It turns out that for me at least (OS-X 10.5.8, python 2.7.3, numpy 1.6.2) This version is about twice as fast as the other version which uses `np.vectorize`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('factarr*cplxarr.real+(1j)*cplxarr.imag',setup='from __main__ import factarr,cplxarr')
21.008132934570312
>>> timeit('f(cplxarr.real * factarr, cplxarr.imag)',setup='from __main__ import factarr,cplxarr; import numpy as np; f=np.vectorize(np.complex)')
46.52931499481201
```

It doesn't seem to make much of a difference between using `np.complex` and `complex` provided by python:

```
>>> timeit('f(cplxarr.real * factarr, cplxarr.imag)',setup='from __main__ import  factarr,cplxarr; import numpy as np; f=np.vectorize(complex)')
44.87726283073425
```

---

**THE CURRENT LEADER IN THE TIMINGS STANDINGS** (proposed by eryksun in the comments below)

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a = cplxarr.copy(); a.real *= factarr ',setup='from __main__ import factarr,cplxarr')
8.336654901504517
```

And proof that it works:

```
>>> a = cplxarr.copy()
>>> a.real *= factarr 
>>> a
array([ 0.5+2.j,  1.8+1.j,  1.4-2.j])
```

This obviously would be even faster if you wanted to do the operation in place (and could therefore leave the copy off).

Comment: (+1) I prefer your version to mine.

Comment: @NPE -- I'd have to `timeit` before I come up with a preferred solution ;-)

Comment: Thank you; that is the disassembling/reassembling method, of course. I will not pick your answer for a little while, giving someone the chance to offer a different answer, if there is such a beast.

Comment: @tzot -- Waiting is probably a good idea.  My gut tells me that there should be a better way (but my guts have been wrong before).

Comment: @tzot: Did you want this done in place? That's just `cplxarr.real *= factarr`. Otherwise, you could try a `[:]` copy followed by an in-place scale of the `real` component.

Comment: @eryksun -- I think that `ndarray.copy` is probably better for copying.  `[:]` should return a view, not a copy when dealing with np.ndarrays.  But just updating the real component in place is a good idea.

Comment: @eryksun -- I hope you don't mind, I've added that version to the timings (it's the current leader by factor of about 2.5).  I suppose this makes sense too since my version has 2 multiplications and an addition whereas yours only has a single multiplication.

Comment: Yes, eryksun's suggestion is exactly what I wanted; if eryksun adds it as their answer, I will pick that one instead of this one, but I am sure this answer will be the local king of upvotes :)

Comment: Thanks, guys. I understand that eryksun's answer is the only-one really in-place, while the initial suggestion by mgilson includes lots of temporary arrays; this explains the difference in speed.